# Laptop-sized Keyboard with Bluetooth, Wireless, & Wired

Tags: keyboards

I am looking for a laptop-sized keyboard (similar to those on Dell 15-16" laptops) that would fit in my backpack.

I am looking for recommendations for a wireless back-lit keyboard which also supports bluetooth as I wish to use it with my tablet too.

A combo package with a mouse would be nice as I need a mouse to control my laptop when connected to an external monitor. An integrated touchpad would be preferable & eliminate the need for the mouse. (tough already?)

A plus, if it exists, would be to have a usb-wired functionality which allows it to be used with a usb cable (& charge too?).

Preference is for one without a keypad but I also consider ones with it.

Asking for too much?

Update: I decided o go with cjm's recommendation of the [Drevo 71 mechanical keyboard (black with blue switch)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H6DWV8M). Though its bluetooth performance was a concern as reported by some reviewers but it was the only option that fits all criteria.
I also ordered the "[TeckNet BM306 Souris Bluetooth mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q7V0W4)"

I will report on the recommendation once I receive it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking for a mechanical keyboard, [this Drevo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H6DWV8M) fits all your criteria: it has no number pad, it has backlights, and it's Bluetooth-compatible.

Comment: Awesome suggestion @cjm. I will confirm when I decide if this will be it as it is very likely. +1 for having Page Up/Down keys which I didn't mention.
Q: I was indeed looking for mechanical ones, but what is the main difference with others? Sound?

Comment: @user10853 Sounds better (depending on which switch you choose) and generally feels much nicer to type on than normal keyboards.

Comment: Mechanical switches also are fairly standardized, so you can swap your keycaps easier.

Comment: Cool. Though bluetooth performace seems a concern for speed writing but I won't be using it for that purpose.
Also, do you have a similar suggestion with a keypad? (adjusted the question)

Comment: Also, speaking of echanical keyboards, that makes it easy to switch keys if I wish to over to another layout (Dvorak/Coleman), right?
Excuse my questions if not related to the main one.

Comment: @user10853 Yes, it makes it easier to move the keys around (though you'll end up with the bumpy keys in the wrong spots if you don't order custom bump keys)

Comment: I haven't until now. It seems the only option available that satisfies my requirements + being a mechanical keyboard. I also ordered a bluetooth mouse to go with it. I'll update my question + get back to you when I receive it.

Comment: I've been using it for a couple of days. It is what I was searching for. Two downsides: performance lags with bluetooth & blue switches are not suitable for office work. I would up-vote but can't. I really don't get how one would down vote your answer. Thanks

Comment: Blues and Greens are clicky. Not good if you have to share an office or talk on the phone when you type. Super enjoyable otherwise.

Comment: aha. This keyboard is being offered in blue & black switches. How does the black compare to the blue?

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with black switches, but they are heavier than Blues, quiet, and linear (so they're smooth all the way down, rather than having an obvious point you can feel to indicate the key was pressed)

Answer (score 0):

This [Bluetooth Keyboard KVAGO Backlight Illuminated](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01G6LA72M) fits all of your criteria: it is small (28.4 x 14.8 x 2.2 cm), it is backlit, is wireless and has a USB cable.

Here are some specs:

- Modulation System: GFSK
- Operating Voltage: 3.0-5.0V
- Working current: 2.5-3.5MA
- Standby Current: 0.3mA
- Sleeping Current: 0.1mA
- Charging Current: 200mA
- Working distance: 10m
- Uninterrupted work time: 55 to 70 hours
- Charging time: 4-5 hours
- Standby time: 60 days
- Operating voltage: 3.7~4.2V(Power by Li-on)
- Battery capacity without backlight version: 150mah
- Battery capacity with a backlit version: 400mah
- Lithium Battery Capacity: 400mA
- Lithium Battery Life: 3 years
- Key Strength: 70-90g
- Key Life: 5 million strokes

Cost: £21.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend the **[Rii K12BT Ultra Slim Portable Mini Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017QZ483G)**. It does everything you listed (well, it can charge while connected via bluetooth, but close enough), and it is cheap and well-reviewed.

Comment: Good suggestion. I forgot to mention that I need a back-lit one though.